# Homotopy type of certain maps on complex grassmanian

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, matrices, grassmannians

$G(k,n)$ is the complex grassmanian which is homeomorphic to the space of projections in $M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ with trace $k$.  So  we can Identify $G(k,n)$ with $$\{A\in M_{n}(\mathbb{C})\mid A=A^{*}=A^{2},\;\;trac(A)=k\}$$

With this  matrix  interpretation, we define two  maps from $G(k,n)$  to  $G(2k,2n)$. Our quesion is that :

> Are these maps homotpic maps?:

The maps are $f(X)=X\otimes I_{2}$ and $g(X)=I_{2}\otimes X$

Comment: Your identification is not correct. $G(k,n)$ is a projective variety, it has no nontrivial map into $M_n(\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: abx, he's using * in his formula; this is not an algebraic identification. The map backwards is $A \mapsto image(A)$.

Comment: Oops! OK, sorry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $U$ be the matrix which sends $e_i$ to $e_{2i}$ and $e_{i+n}$ to $e_{2i+1}$ for $0\leq i<n$.  Then $f(X)=Ug(X)U^{-1}$.  You can join $U$ to $I$ by a path in $U(n)$, and this gives a homotopy between $f$ and $g$.